# Performance problems with updating/deleting >100K rows with MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops, updates

1. Imagine there is a table with 1M rows with categories 1-100.
2. I need to update rows where f.e. category=10 (there are let's say 150k rows).
3. I will update 120k rows and need to delete 30k rows.

**First idea:**
Currently I am using on beginning update of all rows to 0 and on update change this value to 1. Then delete all rows where category=10 and update=0.

There is problem with performance to update 150k rows to 0 where category=10. Sometimes it takes 30s because there could be 200k rows not only 30k.

**Second idea**
On the beginning, loop all 150k rows to keep id's in array, then fill a new array with updated ids and at the end use array_diff to get the remaining ids to delete.

There is also problem with performance to make sql like "... where id in (...30k ids...)".

Do you guys using something better to solve this work?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't understand, if you are able to update rows folowing a criteria ( WHERE ...) You should be able to delete by using the negative crtiria (WHER NOT (...) )

Comment: @Dri372 No. Imagine, there is a feed of 1M products. Those which are not in feed anymore should be deleted. I don't know which they are and how many are there. I'm doing loop cross feed and updating products found in feed. Everything else need to delete from db.

Comment: @Dri372 I could use query like "WHERE NOT IN (...)" but with ~150k ids? Need to make some smartest solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variation on your first idea:** Define your flag column as a timestamp instead of a boolean, then you don't have to take 30 seconds to initialize it to 0. Just update that timestamp to NOW() as you update rows. Once you are done, any rows where the flag column is older than your first updated row should be deleted. I'm assuming this update/delete task will be done again periodically, but the timestamp should still work as long as the tasks do not overlap.

**Variation on your second idea:** Don't run a query `DELETE FROM imagine WHERE id IN(...30k ids...)` predicate. Instead, you may run a series of `DELETE FROM imagine WHERE id IN (...100 ids...)`. Loop over your list of id's and delete in batches of 100 at a time. You'll need to run 300 DELETE statements this way, but it's easy to write the loop.

Comment: Both solutions are great choice! Thank you. At the first solution. Why use timestamp structure not only INT and update like time() in php, then delete everything older than the first updated row? Structure timestamp in mysql is like "2021-06-14 20:28:06". Is it possible to delete everything < 2021-06-14 20:28:06? Or don't know anything?

Comment: Okay, after Googling, now I know that it's possible to delete all rows older then "2021-06-14 20:28:06". I thought, it's some kind of format that needs to be converted to "1623696480" for example. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Only last supplementary question. Is it faster to delete all rows older than "2021-06-14 20:28:06" than delete all rows where something=0?

Comment: It's the same number of rows either way. That's likely to be the greater impact to performance.

Comment: After test of delete 200k rows from 200k table, both queries (delete where something=0 or something<"2021-06-14 20:28:06") takes **~0,7s**. There is probably no difference BUT it doesn't matter if your idea with initial updating rows saves much more time as before.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1bis, if you are looking for performance

add dinamically a new field with default value 0 is faster than update 30K rows for an existnig field.

at the end you can delete this field, that's also a quick command.

Comment: They are default as 0. In update they are 1 and then in next update they are still 1 so I need to change it back to 0 and this takes some time to update 30k or 200k rows to 0 as I am writting above.

Comment: It sees you did not understand my answer, of course update takes time but i wrote to create the field dynamically no need to update to 0. It's far quicker than upate and probably to work with timestamp. I update by answer by adding dynamicaly but it should be clear as I ended it by delting the field.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. It could be solution but I think it's one more unnecessary step as needed. Anyway, thank you for new kind of view for this problem.

Comment: Thank for the review, if you do test let us know versus using timestamp ....

Comment: To create a new column with default 0 takes "nothing". But it takes too too much time to remove it on the end. I need to manipulate with about 30k rows in real and with adding/removing column with 1M rows. Good idea but not applicable on big tables. 1M is only example. There will be more than 10M rows.

Comment: Interesting ; very quick survey with 1M rows- mysql : add column 1, drop colum 50 : update : 1500 - postgresql : add 1 , drop 1, update 1500

Comment: @Dri372 - 1500 seconds?  Milliseconds?  What version of MySQL?  (There were recent changes in this area.)

Answer (score 0):

Large Updates (or Deletes) are costly because of the need to save the old rows in case of a crash.

If this is a one-time task *and* you do not need to worry about blocking other activity during the Updates, then simply do the queries, and let them take minutes if necessary.

If you have some other constraints, please specify.  And please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, plus the proposed Update and Delete statements.

For some situations, it is better to walk through the table using the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Do it 1000 rows at a time.  That is, first find the range of ids that span that range, then execute each of the Updates and Deletes, but limit (via `WHERE`) to the range.  (In some cases, they may modify no rows, but that is OK.)  `COMMIT` after each chunk.

More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: Hi @rick-james Have/can your read my last comment compating mysql et postgresl. It's very approximative, but can interresting to go deeper ... should you be ok to make soome cross tests?